# Why is mic audio not working one-way in Google Hangouts on Windows 7 and Chrome

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone, google-hangouts

I am using Google Hangouts via Chrome on Windows 7.
Video is working fine both ways, i.e. when in a hangout call, I am able to see the other person and they are able to see me. Audio was also working - both ways - some time earlier, i.e. I could hear the other person and they could hear me. Recently something has changed, and now the other person cannot hear me. I can still hear them fine. I have tried changing some settings in Control Panel -> Sound, such as disabling and then enabling the sound device, but it does not work. To help with debugging the problem, I tried Skype calls, including with the same friend with whom I tried troubleshooting the Hangouts issue. In Skype, both audio and video are working fine in both directions.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check whether the particular device is selected in settings page for microphone and speaker

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked. It seems okay. Here are two relevant images - screenshots of Control Panel -> Sound with 1) the Speakers tab and 2) the Mic tab showing: http://imgur.com/oexBfJi and http://imgur.com/aGySwvs

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, unfortunately I only saw your question now. I don't always notice the notification at the top of the SO/SU screens. Thanks for asking. No, I did not get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue as the person unable to hear the other party.  I found that my issue was that my ad blocker plugin (uBlock Origin) was somehow interfering.  When I disabled the ad blocker for Hangouts, I was able to hear the other party and the video display became a lot less jerky.

I recommend trying Hangouts in Incognito mode (and disable your ad blocker extension as well if you allow it in Incognito).

If your other party can't hear you, recommend to them that they try these steps as the issue is likely on their end.

Answer (score -1):

I had to disable the extension "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" (and reload the Hangouts page) to get my Hangouts audio to work in both directions in Chrome on a Mac; to debug similar problems I'd start by disabling all extensions using chrome://extensions/

Comment: Can someone please let me know why they downvoted this, so I can give better answers in the future?